# Troubles setting up private name servers WHM/cPanel

Tags: dns, cpanel, whm, nameservers

So I am trying to set up name servers for my cPanel so when my clients point their domain to ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com their domain will work.

I have my A records NS1 and NS2 pointed to two different IPs on my server (the ones that get assigned when I click assign IP address.

As shown in the image here: http://prntscr.com/8vui67

Although the records don't seem to be working for my clients.

Here is my "show ip address usage"

http://prntscr.com/8vuikz

The name servers don't seem to be displayed here ( is that a problem ).

Sorry for what seems like a noob question, I have been working at this for several hours and I just keep running in circles.

I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have completed the following steps:

[1] Assigned IPs to nameservers from WHM (From screen capture, it seems you already did it)

[2] Register your private nameservers from your registrar where your domain is registered.

[3] Add "A" records for ns1 and ns2 in the DNS zone of your domain (which is used for nameservers)

Now you should be able to use the nameservers without any problem.

### EDIT:

Your domain nalhost.com is using your registrar's DNS so you will need to create A record in the DNS zone of your registrar. If you have already registered your private nameservers and add both A records, your nameservers should work. Are you receiving any error message while using your private nameservers?

Comment: Ok I have done so. My name servers are ns1.nalhost.com and ns2.nalhost.com can you take a look and see the problem? My A records have been set, seem be to registered on my domain and within the control panel.